VS Code editor not able to ignore comment lines
I am using Visual Studio Code for writing Latex documents, using snippets both in math environment and global environment, with different triggering methods. However, if I write a comment in Latex which contains one dollar symbol, then everything below that comment is interpreted as belonging to math mode. For example, if I have a snippet which only works in math environment for writing Greek characters automatically when I type alpha->\alpha, mu->\mu..., then below that comment line, the following line will be printed (as an example, I intend to write "a nurse told me that one kilogram of pineapples cost as much as one kilogram of mussels")
% $
A \nurse told me that one kilogram of \pineapples cost as \much as one kilogram of \mussels.
As you can see, correcting this is a cumbersome task, and this can be even worse, when more snippets are added, that->t\hat{}, kilogram->ki\logram, cost->\cos. I guess that this must be related to the editor, because compilation throws no errors.
I upload a gif of the wrong performance.

I have looked for ignoring lines beginning with % character in the settings.json file, however this is not available.
Another solution might be modify regular expressions of snippets, but I think the problem is the editor.
